# Echo message based on condition failure bash

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, exit, exit-code

Is there a simple way to echo a message for a failure in a multi conditional if statement rather than keeping track of a flag or something.

Example is

```
if [ $i != 0 ] && (cat file.txt | grep -q sometext)
then
    echo allGood
    exit 0
else
    echo either i is not 0 or file.txt doesnt contain sometext
    exit -1
fi
```

I want to be more concise on which of the conditionals failed while remaining efficient if possible. So instead of the echo being one or other failed, in the if statement itself if first one fails I echo corresponding failure and then I just exit with exit status

Comment: Your echo text "*file.txt doesnt contain sometext*" is not necessarily true.  It `grep` returns 1 then this is the case but it could fail for other reasons, for example "No such file or directory" or "Permission denied".

Comment: Also, `exit -1` is not strictly correct.  You can exit any integer between 0 and 255.  On most platforms -1 will be interpreted as 255, but relying on that is confusing.  If you want to exit 255 then say so.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
[ $i != 0 ] || echo i is zero && exit -1
grep -q sometext file.txt || echo sometext not found && exit -1
echo all good && exit 0
```

(note that I've also removed your [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat))